# How to show that the solutions which satisfies the ODE $f(x)f'(x)=\varepsilon f''(x)$ ($\varepsilon>0$) for all $x$ are constant functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am trying to show that the ODE $f(x)f'(x)=\varepsilon f''(x)$ ($\varepsilon>0$) has only constant functions as its solution if the solution exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I tried to show this by assuming that $f$ is not a constant to lead to a contradiction. However, I am stuck with going further from this relationship: $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\{f(x)\}^{2}\right)'=(\varepsilon f'(x))'.$$

For the solution to be constant ($f(x) \equiv \mathrm{constant}$), $f'(x)$ must be identically equal to $0$ but I cannot figure out how to derive such conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

As you found,
$$
f'(x)=\frac1{2ε}(f(x)^2+C)
$$
For $C\ge 0$ it can easily be computed that this leads to a pole in finite time.

For $C=-c^2<0$ you get bounded solutions in the interval $-c\le f(x)\le c$ between the two constant solutions of this equation $$f'(x)=\frac1{2ε}(f(x)+c)(f(x)-c).$$ I do not see how that is compatible with the claim.

Are you meant to prove this claim for the perturbation series in $ε$?

Comment: The original problem was to prove that the only steady-state solutions of $u_{t}+uu_{x}-\varepsilon u_{xx}=0$, $u(x,0)=f(x)$ which exist for all $x$ are constant functions. Since $u_{t}=0$ for steady-state condition, $u(x,t)=u(x,0)=f(x)$ and  I got $f(x)f'(x)=\varepsilon f''(x)$. Do you mean that something's wrong with the problem?

Comment: Then the most likely interpretation is that $f$ has to be independent of the mollification coefficient $ε$. This in turn means that the equation in question has to be valid for all $ε$, and thus consequently also for $ε=0$, which directly leads to only constant solutions.